# How to send arduino data to php code

Tags: arduino-mega, rfid

I'm new to arduino. I'm doing a project where I need to send a RFID UID to php code. The UID will be detected by the arduino and the rest will happen at the php side. for that I need to get this UID at oho side. I'm using RFID-RC522 and arduino mega 2560. how can I do this?

also I found couple of posts about ethernet. is it the only solution for this? if I use an ethernet shield will it block any ports which I'm using on arduino for connecting the RFID things?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SE:Arduino.

Shields are usually designed so that the pins are still fully accessible.  The shield has a set of male connectors on the underside and female connectors (same as your Arduino) on the top side.  Just Google a pic of a shield and you will see what I mean.

Ethernet is not the only choice, there is Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, NFC, radio and probably a point to point light link.  What ever communication method you select, you would need to use HTTP POST messages to your server, so your server will have to implement a REST or SOAP interface. (There are probably other ways, but I'm not a webbie so you will need to ask them on the correct SE forum)

Once you have created your message on the Arduino you send it to your shield, probably by a function call or over a serial interface.  You'll get an OK back and all is good.

To find code that does this, just search, someone will have written and example, Adafruit and the Arduino.cc sites are good places to start.

Comment: I checked about the ethernet shield from following link https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield but there, they are mentioning that "Arduino communicates with both the W5500 and SD card using the SPI bus (through the ICSP header). This is on digital pins  50, 51, and 52 on the Mega. Pin 10 is used to select the W5500 and pin 4 for the SD card. These pins cannot be used for general I/O. On the Mega, the hardware SS pin, 53 must be kept as an output or the SPI interface won't work." But I'm using the same set of ports for the RFID.. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Wi-Fi, I suggest you to use **ESP8266-01**, it's cheap and usefull ! With this chip you can send all data to your server!

Comment: You could probably do every thing on an ESP8266-12, twice as much processing power, loads more memory.  The only real draw back is five less analog ports, but that's what I2C ADCs where invented for :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of WiFi and ethernet shields, most of them(if not all) will not block your RFID especially if you use Mega2560. You must have a network connection for talking with php server, so YES, you need WiFi or ethernet shield.

Hope i'll help.

Yoav